# In android application, how to know the application is first runtime?

Tags: android

can you tell me, how to know the application in first run time, because i have some attribute just need one time....but i don't know what method to do that?
Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple, really. Use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Example:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if (prefs.getBoolean("first-time", true)) {
    // do something, the app is being launched for the first time!
    prefs.edit().setBoolean("first-time", false).commit(); // record the fact that the app has been started at least once
}
```

You can put this snippet in the `onCreate()` method of your main activity, for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();
int runCount = 0;
if(settings.contains("RunCount")) { // your app run before
     // this many times:
     runCount = settings.getInt("RunCount", 0);
}


prefEditor.putInt("RunCount", ++runCount);
prefEditor.commit();
```